# Find an isomorphism for this map

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G = (\mathbb{R}^*,\cdot)$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero real numbers. $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$ has operation $0+0=0, 0+1=1, 1+0=1, 1+1=0$ and is a group. Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the group of all reals with addition, I want to find a bijective homomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow G$.

I think I am close to solving this. I want $\phi$ such that for every $a\in G$ there exists a unique $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $\phi(x,y)=a$. From corollary in Artin's Algebra, I know $ker\phi$ must be equal to the subgroup $\{1\}$ of $G$ for $\phi$ to be a homomorphism. This means that $\phi((0,0))=e_G=1\in G$. I can do basically the same operations for all values of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and all $n\in  \mathbb{Z}$, but I do not know how to construct a presentable homomorphism (bijective) for such a circumstance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you've seen the proof that $(\Bbb R,+)\not\cong (\Bbb R^*,\times)$ because there is an element of $(\Bbb R^*,\times)$ (namely, $-1$) that has order $2$ while there is no such element in $(\Bbb R,+)$.

And you must know that $\exp$ is an isomorphism from $(\Bbb R,+)$ to $(\Bbb R_+^*,\times)$.

So the only thing bothering you to get an isomorphism from $(\Bbb R,+)$ to $(\Bbb R^*,\times)$ is that you have the negative numbers in $(\Bbb R^*,\times)$. So you'll add $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ to represent the sign.

$$\varphi:\begin{array}((\Bbb R,+)\times \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to (\Bbb R^*,\times)\\(x,y)\mapsto (-1)^ye^x\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

Identify $\mathbb{Z}_2$ instead as the group $\{1, -1\}$ with multiplication, and consider the function $\mathbb{R} \times \{1, -1\} \to \mathbb{R}^*$ given by $(x, a) \mapsto ae^x$ (for an inverse, consider $y \mapsto (\ln y, \text{sign}(y)))$.